# K3S SQLite slow on NFS

Tags: sqlite, kubernetes, nfs, k3s

I have an application running on my home cluster.
My cluster is running K3S.
The cluster exists of 5 Raspberry Pi's 3B and 1 Ubuntu VM.
One of my deployments is Domoticz.
This uses a SQLite database to store data.
I'm using this as a StorageClass. https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner
The NFS is hosted in OpenMediaVault with arguments subtree_check,insecure,no_root_squash

When I store this database (14MB) on a PV volume linked to an NFS Storage Class, the applications becomes very slow.
When I use the Storage Class local-path, the application is as fast.
Problem is now that when that node dies, the Deployment doesn't start because of the node-affinity linked to the PVC.
I'm out of idea's to fix this issue.

Is there another SC better suited to my setup?
Is there a tweak to the SC local-path, so it's not linked to a node? (yes I know, database will not be transferred to the new node)

Comment: You shoud add more about your configuration, how exactly is your NFS server configured? What options have you used on shares?

Comment: What about using [Longhorn](https://longhorn.io/)? From [the Rancher documentation](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/storage/): `NOTE:
At this time Longhorn only supports amd64 and arm64 (experimental).` [An article](https://dev.to/bbende/k3s-on-raspberry-pi-volumes-and-storage-1om5) about a possible use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using longhorn instead of NFS.
Thanks Andrew Skorkin for the tip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: “use longhorn” isn’t a great answer. “here is how longhorn is a solution to your problem…” would be better.